# How do I handle page refreshing with an AngularJS Single Page Application

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

Two problems have troubled me as I have learned angular:

1. *How do I restore state when the user refreshes the page or hits the back button?*
2. *How do I share data between scopes belonging to different controllers?*

Below I show a simple solution that makes use of client-side session storage. It allows for both the sharing of common data and the automatic restoration of state after a user refreshes the page or hits the back button.

Note: The solution below proved essential to answer the following question:

[How do I get the Back Button to work with an AngularJS ui-router state machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22247294/776476)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution depends on the `SessionService` class shown below. The syntax is coffeescript.

**SessionService Class**

```
class SessionService
    scopes:[]

    setStorage:(key, value) ->
        scope[key] = value for scope in @scopes
        value =  if value is undefined then null else JSON.stringify value
        sessionStorage.setItem key, value

    getStorage:(key)->
        sessionValue = sessionStorage.getItem key
        if sessionValue == "undefined"
            return null
        JSON.parse sessionValue

    register:(scope)->
        for key, value of sessionStorage
            scope[key] = if value? and value != "undefined" then JSON.parse(value) else null
        @scopes.push scope
        scope.$on '$destroy', =>
            @scopes = @scopes.filter (s) -> s.$id != scope.$id

    clear: ->
        @setStorage(key, null) for key of sessionStorage

    isAuthenticated: ->
        @accessor 'isAuthenticated', value

    user:(value=null) ->
        @accessor 'user', value

    # other storage items go here 

    accessor:(name, value)->
        return @getStorage name unless value?
        @setStorage name, value

angular
.module 'app.Services'
.service 'sessionService', SessionService
```

The `SessionService` class defines the `isAuthenticated` property (simple bool) and the `user` property (a complex object) . The values of these properties are automatically stringified / parsed as they are stored / retrieved using the client-side local `sessionStorage` object supplied by javascript.

You add *more properties as required*. Like `$rootScope` you add properties sparingly. Unlike `$rootScope` the property values are still available after a page refresh or back button click.

The service allows any number of scopes to be registered with it. When a scope is registered all the stored values in `sessionStorage` are automatically assigned to that scope. In this way all the registered scopes always have access to all the session properties.

When a property value is updated, all the registered scopes have their corresponding values updated.

When angular destroys a scope it is automatically removed from the list of registered scopes to save wasting resources.

If a user refreshes the page or hits the back button then the angular application is forced to restart. Normally this would mean you would have to reconstruct your current state. The `SessionService` does this for you automatically as each scope will have its values restored from local storage when they are registered during the app initialisation.

So now it is easy to solve the problem of both sharing data between scopes as well as restoring values when the user refreshes or hits the back button.

Here is some sample angular code that shows how to use the `SessionService` class.

**Register a scope with SessionService in some Controller**

```
angular
.module 'app'
.controller 'mainCtrl', ($scope, $state, session, security) ->
    #register the scope with the session service
    session.register $scope

    #hook up the 'login' method (see security service)
    $scope.login = security.login

    # check the value of a session property
    # it may well be true if the page has been refreshed
    if session.isAuthenticated
        $state.go('home')
    else
        $state.go('login')
```

**Set Session values in a service**

```
 class SecurityService
    @$inject:['$http','sessionService', 'api']
    constructor:(@http, @session, @api) ->

    login:(username, password) =>
        @http.get "#{@api.base}/security/login/credentials/#{username}/#{password}"
        .success (user)=>
            @session.isAuthenticated = true
            @session.user = user
        .error (ex)=>
            # process error

angular
.module 'app'
.service 'securityService', SecurityService
```

**Use Session values in UI (Jade template)**

```
div(ng-show="isAuthenticated")
    div Hello {{user.Name}}
```

Comment: is there a non-coffeescript version of this? Is this also the only possible solution? Thanks!

Comment: You can convert the coffeescript to javascript and back again here: http://js2coffee.org/. There are bound to be other / better solutions and at first I assumed there must be an easy, angular way of handling such a common thing as the back/refresh buttons. But I could not find it so what you see here is my best, current shot at making it work. I hope somebody posts a better solution.

Comment: @edzillion Can you explain why people should *not* post coffeescript-syntax solutions for angular? Since coffeescript is a facade for the underlying javascript, is the point that we should not be using javascript?

Comment: I guess it's just inefficient for the most of us that don't use cofeescrpt/typescript etc. to have to convert (and possibly introduce errors) the code before I can use it.

Comment: Please note that the domain provided for converting CoffeeScript to plain JavaScript is dead, this appears to be the replacement: http://js2.coffee/ . Also, since I don't know CoffeeScript, reading the JS was way easier to then translate back into TypeScript. If asked, I will gladly update the response with TS versions (in addition to what is there).

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same issue and chose to use angular cookies, since the
only state that is not pulled by the template via ng-init is the logged in user
state.

I store the user ID in a cookie on login after I've received the user
model from our server and I clear the user ID cookie on logout.  Then to recover
the logged in user state on a page refresh or back button event, I hook the
`$location` service's `$locationChangeStart` event.  From my experimentation, this
event is triggered at the point the location is about to change but before the
partial/template has been loaded.  This allows the needed state to be loaded just
in time.

I'm not convinced that I don't have a race condition here as
`$scope.loadLoggedInUser(...)` uses asynch $http to load the needed state but so far
it has worked reliably for me.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {
            $log.debug("locationChangeStart");
            if (!$scope.appCtx.models.loggedInUser) {
                var userID = $cookies.get("userID");
                if (!userID) {
                    $scope.doLogout();
                    return;
                }
                $scope.loadLoggedInUser(userID, true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution when you're using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) to configure your server. You have to organize your routing at the client-side in a way that makes your route links as unique regular expressions. In app.js you'll have:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('dataCollector', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',

    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })

        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
            })

        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
}]);

})();
```

In this example all the routes, except `'/'`, can be written in a regular expression schema `[A-Za-z]`. Having this, the server.js file would be like this:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var http = require('http');
 var fs = require('fs');
 var path = require('path');

 var app = express();
 app.use(express.static('public'));

 app.get(/[A-Za-z]/, function (req, res) {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
 });


 http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

Now every `GET` request that matches the regex `[A-Za-z]` will make a response with `index.html` (that are our routes called when refreshing a page e.g. `/about`). Any other `GET` request will response with a file from the `/public` directory (here every file with the extension `*.html`). This allows to refresh the AngularJS SPA in a proper way.