# How do I get the Back Button to work with an AngularJS ui-router state machine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

I have implemented an angularjs single page application using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Originally I identified each state using a distinct url however this made for unfriendly, GUID packed urls.

So I have now defined my site as a much simpler state-machine. The states are not identified by urls but are simply transitioned to as required, like this:

**Define Nested States**

```
angular
.module 'app', ['ui.router']
.config ($stateProvider) ->
    $stateProvider
    .state 'main', 
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
        params: ['locationId']

    .state 'folder', 
        templateUrl: 'folder.html'
        parent: 'main'
        controller: 'folderCtrl'
        resolve:
            folder:(apiService) -> apiService.get '#base/folder/#locationId'
```

**Transition to a Defined State**

```
#The ui-sref attrib transitions to the 'folder' state

a(ui-sref="folder({locationId:'{{folder.Id}}'})")
    | {{ folder.Name }}
```

This system works very well and I love its clean syntax. However, as I am not using urls the back button does not work.

How do I keep my neat ui-router state-machine but enable the back button functionality?

Comment: "states are not identified by urls" -- and there's your problem I suspect. The back button is pretty protected from the code (otherwise people would override it, causing problems). Why not just let angular make better urls, like SO does (OK they may not be using angular, but their url schemse is illustrative)?

Comment: Also, this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications

Comment: Also, since you're not using URLs doesn't that mean that to get to state Z people will have to click thru state X and Y to get to it? That might get annoying.

Comment: will it go with state with different params? @jcollum

Comment: I have no idea, this was too long ago

Answer (score 78, accepted):

### Note

The answers that suggest using variations of `$window.history.back()` have all missed a crucial part of the question: How to *restore the application's state* to the correct state-location as the history jumps (back/forward/refresh). With that in mind; please, read on.

---

Yes, it is possible to have the browser back/forward (history) and refresh whilst running a pure `ui-router` state-machine but it takes a bit of doing.

You need several components:

- *Unique URLs*. The browser only enables the back/forward buttons when you change urls, so you must generate a unique url per visited state. These urls need not contain any state information though.
- *A Session Service*. Each generated url is correlated to a particular state so you need a way to store your url-state pairs so that you can retrieve the state information after your angular app has been restarted by back / forward or refresh clicks.
- *A State History*. A simple dictionary of ui-router states keyed by unique url. If you can rely on HTML5 then you can use the [HTML5 History API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#history), but if, like me, you can't then you can implement it yourself in a few lines of code (see below).
- *A Location Service*. Finally, you need to be able manage both ui-router state changes, triggered internally by your code, and normal browser url changes typically triggered by the user clicking browser buttons or typing stuff into the browser bar. This can all get a bit tricky because it is easy to get confused about what triggered what.

Here is my implementation of each of these requirements. I have bundled everything up into three services:

**The Session Service**

```
class SessionService

    setStorage:(key, value) ->
        json =  if value is undefined then null else JSON.stringify value
        sessionStorage.setItem key, json

    getStorage:(key)->
        JSON.parse sessionStorage.getItem key

    clear: ->
        @setStorage(key, null) for key of sessionStorage

    stateHistory:(value=null) ->
        @accessor 'stateHistory', value

    # other properties goes here

    accessor:(name, value)->
        return @getStorage name unless value?
        @setStorage name, value

angular
.module 'app.Services'
.service 'sessionService', SessionService
```

This is a wrapper for the javascript `sessionStorage` object. I have cut it down for clarity here. For a full explanation of this please see: [How do I handle page refreshing with an AngularJS Single Page Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21407534/776476)

**The State History Service**

```
class StateHistoryService
    @$inject:['sessionService']
    constructor:(@sessionService) ->

    set:(key, state)->
        history = @sessionService.stateHistory() ? {}
        history[key] = state
        @sessionService.stateHistory history

    get:(key)->
        @sessionService.stateHistory()?[key]

angular
.module 'app.Services'
.service 'stateHistoryService', StateHistoryService
```

The `StateHistoryService` looks after the storage and retrieval of historical states keyed by generated, unique urls. It is really just a convenience wrapper for a dictionary style object.

**The State Location Service**

```
class StateLocationService
    preventCall:[]
    @$inject:['$location','$state', 'stateHistoryService']
    constructor:(@location, @state, @stateHistoryService) ->

    locationChange: ->
        return if @preventCall.pop('locationChange')?
        entry = @stateHistoryService.get @location.url()
        return unless entry?
        @preventCall.push 'stateChange'
        @state.go entry.name, entry.params, {location:false}

    stateChange: ->
        return if @preventCall.pop('stateChange')?
        entry = {name: @state.current.name, params: @state.params}
        #generate your site specific, unique url here
        url = "/#{@state.params.subscriptionUrl}/#{Math.guid().substr(0,8)}"
        @stateHistoryService.set url, entry
        @preventCall.push 'locationChange'
        @location.url url

angular
.module 'app.Services'
.service 'stateLocationService', StateLocationService
```

The `StateLocationService` handles two events:

- *locationChange*. This is called when the browsers location is changed, typically when the back/forward/refresh button is pressed or when the app first starts or when the user types in a url. If a state for the current location.url exists in the `StateHistoryService` then it is used to restore the state via ui-router's `$state.go`.
- *stateChange*. This is called when you move state internally. The current state's name and params  are stored in the `StateHistoryService` keyed by a generated url. This generated url can be anything you want, it may or may not identify the state in a human readable way. In my case I am using a state param plus a randomly generated sequence of digits derived from a guid (see foot for the guid generator snippet). The generated url is displayed in the browser bar and, crucially, added to the browser's internal history stack using `@location.url url`. Its adding the url to the browser's history stack that enables the forward / back buttons.

The big problem with this technique is that calling `@location.url url` in the `stateChange` method will trigger the `$locationChangeSuccess` event and so call the `locationChange` method. Equally calling the `@state.go` from `locationChange` will trigger the `$stateChangeSuccess` event and so the `stateChange` method. This gets very confusing and messes up the browser history no end.

The solution is very simple. You can see the `preventCall` array being used as a stack (`pop` and `push`). Each time one of the methods is called it prevents the other method being called one-time-only. This technique does not interfere with the correct triggering of the $ events and keeps everything straight.

Now all we need to do is call the `HistoryService` methods at the appropriate time in the state transition life-cycle. This is done in the AngularJS Apps `.run` method, like this:

**Angular app.run**

```
angular
.module 'app', ['ui.router']
.run ($rootScope, stateLocationService) ->

    $rootScope.$on '$stateChangeSuccess', (event, toState, toParams) ->
        stateLocationService.stateChange()

    $rootScope.$on '$locationChangeSuccess', ->
        stateLocationService.locationChange()
```

**Generate a Guid**

```
Math.guid = ->
    s4 = -> Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1)
    "#{s4()}#{s4()}-#{s4()}-#{s4()}-#{s4()}-#{s4()}#{s4()}#{s4()}"
```

With all this in place, the forward / back buttons and the refresh button all work as expected.

Comment: in the example of the SessionService above, I think the accessor: method should be using `@setStorage` and `@getStorage` rather than `@get/setSession'.

Comment: Which language is used for this example. Doesn't seem to be angular that i am familiar with.

Comment: The language was javascript, the syntax was coffeescript.

Comment: Compared to the Guillaume Massé solution below, this looks very complicated. What is the added value ?

Comment: @jlguenego You have a functional browser history/ bowser back and forth buttons and URL's that you can bookmark.

Comment: @jlguenego - the answers that suggest using variations of `$window.history.back()` have missed a crucial part of the question. The point was to restore the application's _state_ to the correct state-location as the history jumps (back/forward/refresh). This would normally be achieved by supplying the state data via the URI. The question asked how to jump between state-locations _without_ (explicit) URI state data. Given this constraint, it is not sufficient to just replicate the back button because this relies on the URI state data to re-establish the state-location.

Comment: You are passing a parameter to `.pop()`, which isn't valid JS. I'm not familiar with coffeescript, but does this do something or is it a typo?

Answer (score 46):

```
app.run(['$window', '$rootScope', 
function ($window ,  $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.goBack = function(){
    $window.history.back();
  }
}]);

<a href="#" ng-click="goBack()">Back</a>
```

Comment: love this! ... lol ... for clarity `$window.history.back` is doing the magic not `$rootScope` ... so go back could be bound to your navbar directive scope if you want.

Comment: @BenjaminConant For people who don't know how to implement this, you simply put the `$window.history.back();` in a function to be called upon `ng-click`.

Comment: correct rootScope is only to make the function accessible in any template

Comment: Chicken Dinner.

Answer (score 23):

After testing different proposals, I found that the easiest way is often the best.

If you use angular ui-router and that you need a button to go back best is this:

```
<button onclick="history.back()">Back</button>
```

or

```
<a onclick="history.back()>Back</a>
```

// Warning don't set the href or the path will be broken.

Explanation:
Suppose a standard management application.
Search object -> View object -> Edit object

**Using the angular solutions**
From this state :

> Search -> View -> Edit

To :

> Search -> View

Well that's what we wanted except if now you click the browser back button you'll be there again :

> Search -> View -> Edit

And that is not logical

**However using the simple solution**

```
<a onclick="history.back()"> Back </a>
```

from :

> Search -> View -> Edit

after click on button :

> Search -> View

after click on browser back button :

> Search

Consistency is respected. :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for the simplest "back" button, then you could set up a directive like so:

```
    .directive('back', function factory($window) {
      return {
        restrict   : 'E',
        replace    : true,
        transclude : true,
        templateUrl: 'wherever your template is located',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.navBack = function() {
            $window.history.back();
          };
        }
      };
    });
```

Keep in mind this is a fairly unintelligent "back" button because it is using the browser's history. If you include it on your landing page, it will send a user back to any url they came from prior to landing on yours.

Answer (score 3):

**browser's back/forward button solution**
I encountered the same problem and I solved it using the `popstate event` from the $window object and `ui-router's $state object`. A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes.
The `$stateChangeSuccess` and `$locationChangeSuccess` events are not triggered on browser's button click even though the address bar indicates the new location.
So, assuming you've navigated from states `main` to `folder` to `main` again, when you hit `back` on the browser, you should be back to the `folder` route. The path is updated but the view is not and still displays whatever you have on `main`. try this:

```
angular
.module 'app', ['ui.router']
.run($state, $window) {

     $window.onpopstate = function(event) {

        var stateName = $state.current.name,
            pathname = $window.location.pathname.split('/')[1],
            routeParams = {};  // i.e.- $state.params

        console.log($state.current.name, pathname); // 'main', 'folder'

        if ($state.current.name.indexOf(pathname) === -1) {
            // Optionally set option.notify to false if you don't want 
            // to retrigger another $stateChangeStart event
            $state.go(
              $state.current.name, 
              routeParams,
              {reload:true, notify: false}
            );
        }
    };
}
```

back/forward buttons should work smoothly after that.

note: check browser compatibility for window.onpopstate() to be sure

Answer (score 3):

Can be solved using a simple directive "go-back-history", this one is also closing window in case of no previous history.

Directive usage

```
<a data-go-back-history>Previous State</a>
```

Angular directive declaration

```
.directive('goBackHistory', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            elm.on('click', function ($event) {
                $event.stopPropagation();
                if ($window.history.length) {
                    $window.history.back();
                } else {
                    $window.close();  
                }
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Note: Working using ui-router or not.

Answer (score 0):

The Back button wasn't working for me as well, but I figured out that the problem was that I had `html` content inside my main page, in the `ui-view` element.

i.e.

```
<div ui-view>
     <h1> Hey Kids! </h1>
     <!-- More content -->
</div>
```

So I moved the content into a new `.html` file, and marked it as a template in the `.js` file with the routes.

i.e.

```
   .state("parent.mystuff", {
        url: "/mystuff",
        controller: 'myStuffCtrl',
        templateUrl: "myStuff.html"
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

`history.back()` and switch to **previous state** often give effect not that you want. For example, if you have form with tabs and each tab has own state, this  just switched previous tab selected, not return from form. In case nested states, you usually need so think about witch of parent states you want to rollback.

This directive solves problem

```
angular.module('app', ['ui-router-back'])

<span ui-back='defaultState'> Go back </span>
```

It returns to state, that was active **before** button has displayed. Optional `defaultState` is state name that used when no previous state in memory. Also it restores scroll position

Code

```
class UiBackData {
    fromStateName: string;
    fromParams: any;
    fromStateScroll: number;
}

interface IRootScope1 extends ng.IScope {
    uiBackData: UiBackData;
}

class UiBackDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    uiBackDataSave: UiBackData;

    constructor(private $state: angular.ui.IStateService,
        private $rootScope: IRootScope1,
        private $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {
    }

    link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = (scope, element, attrs) => {
        this.uiBackDataSave = angular.copy(this.$rootScope.uiBackData);

        function parseStateRef(ref, current) {
            var preparsed = ref.match(/^\s*({[^}]*})\s*$/), parsed;
            if (preparsed) ref = current + '(' + preparsed[1] + ')';
            parsed = ref.replace(/\n/g, " ").match(/^([^(]+?)\s*(\((.*)\))?$/);
            if (!parsed || parsed.length !== 4)
                throw new Error("Invalid state ref '" + ref + "'");
            let paramExpr = parsed[3] || null;
            let copy = angular.copy(scope.$eval(paramExpr));
            return { state: parsed[1], paramExpr: copy };
        }

        element.on('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (this.uiBackDataSave.fromStateName)
                this.$state.go(this.uiBackDataSave.fromStateName, this.uiBackDataSave.fromParams)
                    .then(state => {
                        // Override ui-router autoscroll 
                        this.$timeout(() => {
                            $(window).scrollTop(this.uiBackDataSave.fromStateScroll);
                        }, 500, false);
                    });
            else {
                var r = parseStateRef((<any>attrs).uiBack, this.$state.current);
                this.$state.go(r.state, r.paramExpr);
            }
        });
    };

    public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = ($state, $rootScope, $timeout) =>
            new UiBackDirective($state, $rootScope, $timeout);
        directive.$inject = ['$state', '$rootScope', '$timeout'];
        return directive;
    }
}

angular.module('ui-router-back')
    .directive('uiBack', UiBackDirective.factory())
    .run(['$rootScope',
        ($rootScope: IRootScope1) => {

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
                (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => {
                    if ($rootScope.uiBackData == null)
                        $rootScope.uiBackData = new UiBackData();
                    $rootScope.uiBackData.fromStateName = fromState.name;
                    $rootScope.uiBackData.fromStateScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    $rootScope.uiBackData.fromParams = fromParams;
                });
        }]);
```