# How to route properly using ui-router within a SPA?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I'm looking for a good solution to set up the routing using `ui-router` within my single page application.
How can I implement a back-button into my application to specify back routing?

Comment: I think managing a routing history by myself like (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22402285/2717428) is unalterable!?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, [but you can make use of `window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history) maybe. The `back()` method has the same behaviour as pressing the back button in your browser.