# Same controller, same template, same resource, but one is a nested state and the other is not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

On my application I have courses and events. There are two ways of showing events (which is the problematic state here):

One is by accessing this week's events ('events' state):

```
.state('events.show',
  url: '/events/:eventId'
  views:
    '@':
      templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('events/show.html') %>'
      controller: 'EventCtrl'
  resolve: { event: EventResolver }
)
```

The other when I select from a list of events scoped to course:

```
.state('courses.show.event',
  url: '/events/:eventId'
  views:
    '@':
      templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('events/show.html') %>'
      controller: 'EventCtrl'
  resolve: { event: EventResolver }
)
```

This really looks like a bad practice because of the duplication, but I'm not sure what should I do here instead, as I'd like to keep a "Back" button in the `events/show.html` template to go back either to the scoped events list in course or back to this week's events depending where the user accessed the resource from.

Is there a better way of keeping the "Back" button going to where I wanted without all this duplication? Should I approach this differently?

Comment: Why not have the `course` page send you to the `events.show` state directly? How is the back button functionality hampered here?

Also, take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247294/how-do-i-get-the-back-button-to-work-with-an-angularjs-ui-router-state-machine)

Comment: It is a "Back" button in the `events/show.html` template which currently is taking to `^`, not the browser native button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scrap the duplication, you could go with a state object definition.

```
var eventsState = {
  url: '/events/:eventId'
  views:
    '@':
      templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('events/show.html') %>'
      controller: 'EventCtrl'
  resolve: { event: EventResolver }  
};


$stateProvider
  .state('events.show', eventsState)
  .state('courses.show.event', eventsState)
```

That would be the path of least resistance as far as I'm concerned, but it's hard to tell what would be the *best* way to go forward - not having seen the entire state tree.

---

A back button that would go back to whichever state you came from could be injected into the controller using a resolve property inside the associated view.

```
views: 
  '@': 
    templateUrl: '....'
    resolve: {
      stateOpener: function ($state) {
        /** 
         * $state does _not_ refer to the $state you transitioned to, 
         * but the $state you came from.
         */
        return $state.current.name;
      }
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $state, stateOpener) {
      $scope.goBack = function () {
        $state.go(stateOpener);
      };
    }
```

You could also look into [ui-router-extras#previousState](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/previous), that would probably be the cleanest way to have your back button go wherever you came from.

And of course, there is the `$window.history` way of doing this, but (imho) you should stick to working within the realm of the state machine and not the browser history.