# angularjs ui router not supporting browser back and forward buttons

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

angularjs ui router not supporting browser back and forward buttons.
Is there any way to achieve it?
If I click browser back button the url in address bar changed but nothing happens

Comment: Maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247294/how-do-i-get-the-back-button-to-work-with-an-angularjs-ui-router-state-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the resolution.
I didn't set the default route, that's the reason it was not working.
After setting default route, all was working fine.

Comment: Hi Prashant, I am having the same issue, can you share how did you set the default route?