# Angular states and Browser back button

Tags: angular-routing

I am trying to adapt the following code:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a2iE17GoEzOfTPoEFYTI?p=preview)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
<title>AngularJS: UI-Router Quick Start</title>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="container">

<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" ui-sref="index">Quick Start</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well" ui-view="LeftMenu"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well" ui-view="Content"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Angular -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- UI-Router -->
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<!-- App Script -->
<script>
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "LeftMenu": {
                    template: '<ul><li><a ui-sref="index.LeftMenuMenu1">Index-Left Menu1</a></li><li><a ui-sref="index.LeftMenuMenu2">Index-Left Menu2</a></li><li><a ui-sref="index.LeftMenuMenu3">Index-Left Menu3</a></li></ul>'
                },
                "Content": {
                    template: "<div ui-view></div>"
                }
            }
        })
    .state('index.LeftMenuMenu1', {
            template: "LeftMenu.Menu1 selected"
    })
    .state('index.LeftMenuMenu2', {
        template: "LeftMenu.Menu2 selected"
     })
     .state('index.LeftMenuMenu3', {
         template: "LeftMenu.Menu3 selected"
     })
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        views: {
            "LeftMenu": {
                template: '<ul><li><a ui-sref="Route1.Menu1">Route1-Left Menu1</a></li><li><a ui-sref="Route1.Menu2">Route1-Left Menu2</a></li><li><a ui-sref="Route1.Menu3">Route1-Left Menu3</a></li></ul>'
            },
            "viewB": {
                template: "route1.viewB"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('route2', {
        url: "/route2",
        views: {
            "LeftMenu": {
                template:'<ul><li><a href="">Route2-Left Menu1</a></li><li><a href="">Route2-Left Menu2</a></li><li><a href="">Route2-Left Menu3</a></li></ul>'
            },
            "viewB": {
                template: "route2.viewB"
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

It definitely works fine. What I'd like to have is when I click on Back button it doesn't go back to the previous vertical state if they were selected, but instead goes back to the previous state on the horizontal menu.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599503/angular-ui-router-back-button-issue/40759653#40759653) to a related question ...