# ui-router changing the previous state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The app has pages, `X`, `Y` and `Z`. So the routing should be as follows I go into page `X` and then select some details and then go to page `Y` and then select some more details and then go to `Z`. So I want that after going to `Z` page once I click window back button it should go to page `X` and not page `Y`. While going from `Y` to `Z`, I also tried adding `{ location: 'replace' }` in `$state.go` but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: Simple solution would be to have only 2 states, X and Z. When you select some details on X page and go to Y, instead of going to Y with `ui.router`, hide the current div and show the div that has contents of the Y. Then upon selecting further details, go to Z using `ui.router`..

Comment: @AdityaParab, I need a different page `Y`

Comment: Do you mean `page` as in it has to have a route?

Comment: yes every page has a different route

Comment: Take a look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247294/how-do-i-get-the-back-button-to-work-with-an-angularjs-ui-router-state-machine#answer-22402285).

Comment: @AbKDs : Please check the answer I just posted. :)

Comment: Yup let me just try that. I think this should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you change a state, Angular will trigger an event called [`$stateChangeStart`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events), you can use that to your advantage.

In your `app.run`, do

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$state){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        //Check if you're going from Z to Y
        if(fromState.name === 'Z' && toState.name === 'Y'){ 
            // if so, first stop the default behavior
            event.preventDefault();
           // then navigate to X
            $state.go('X');
        }
    });
});
```

The browser back button essentially triggers the same event so your problem will be solved with this.

Answer (score 0):

do like this 
give your state in $state.go like.. :
 `$state.go('y')`

Comment: That's the point right, how to do that on the browser back button