# AngularJS, using routes without refreshes on back button

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm using `angularJS` to build a simple single page application using AJAX, but I'm running into a problem when users use the native back button.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'myApp.controllers', myApp.services])

.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
       templateUrl: 'templates/feed.html',
       controller: 'MenuCtrl',
       reloadOnSearch: false
   });

   $routeProvider.when('/checkin/view/:id', {
       templateUrl: 'templates/checkin.html',
       controller: 'MenuCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });


     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

})
```

**UPDATE: moved $http out of controls per feedback, and suggestions:**

And my `services.js` file:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])

 .factory('FeedService', ['$http', function($http){
   var state = {};

  var loadFeed = function(){
       $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: 'http://api.example',
         }).success(function(data){
        // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
           state = data.response;
           console.log(data);
        }).error(function(){
           alert("error");
       });
   };

   loadFeed();

   return {
       getState: function(scope){
           return state;
       }
    };
}])
```

And my `controller.js` file:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, FeedService) { 
    // feedback per second answer
    $scope.items  = FeedService.getState();

})

.controller('CheckinCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.checkin_id = $routeParams.id;
    console.log($routeParams.id);
});
```

My main `index.html` is setup like this:

```
 <body ng-app="untappd">
   <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
```

This works great from navigation from a feed `(/home)`, to a check-in page `(/checkin/view/:id)` but, once the user hits the native back button on the browser or using `window.history.back()`, code in the `controller` is called again, which makes the AJAX call to pull down the user's friend feed. Should I be using `ng-show` instead of using `ng-view` for this use case, and create individual "pages" for each content I want to show? I was concerned with the performance, but it appears that I can't get data to persist in each `ng-view` without it having to re-call the templates. Any guidance here?

**UPDATE: I have changed this to incorporate the Best Practices, by adding the `$http` request at the `services` level, instead of the `controller` level. I still run in to the issue of the getState request being fired, before the the AJAX of the `$http` is complete, thus having an empty state, and nothing to render the `$scope`.**

Comment: You could put the call in a service, cache the response and avoid repetitive calls.

Comment: But how would that work when you want to actually load the page fresh? I would only want to provide a cache result, if the back button is used or pressed. Is there any events I can hook into to determine how the page was navigated to?

Comment: Can't you give the user control over this (e.g. refresh button)? Or expire the data in your service after a given time?

Comment: You need to clean up the code before you worry about the issue you're having.  Controllers should not be doing $http calls, that is the purpose of a service (services are singletons, controllers are not and go out of scope).  Controllers should be used ONLY for setting (writing) to scope.  Properly separate the components.  Take a look at  https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html

Comment: @mortsahl I am new with AngularJS, so I just did a simple prototype and didn't flesh everything out. Thanks for the feedback, and I will look forward to doing that for a production ready version.

Comment: Prototypes too frequently become production code ... do it correctly from the beginning and you won't have to worry about extensive refactoring.

Comment: @mortsahl Thanks - but it was not needed here. While I appreciate your feedback and your advise, calling someone out for not building to "spec" while they are learning the language, isn't called for. A simple, "Here is your answer, and you might want to change this", would have perfect here.

Comment: Giving you the answer doesn't help you learn.  I gave you the advice and resources you need to learn.

Comment: @mortsahl this has been updated on the post to move to services.js

Answer (score 5):

Yep, the Back button and the the Refresh button are a real pain. You have two choices:

1. You keep things simple and just allow your state to be fetched for each location change. This treats a user triggered back button click or a refresh as any normal location change. Data re-fetching can be mitigated by http caching.
2. You maintain your own state on the client and restore it when required, possibly using `SessionStorage` to keep things clean.

I chose the latter option and it all works just fine for me. See these self answered questions for detailed code examples.

- [How do I get the Back Button to work with an AngularJS ui-router state machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22247294/776476)
- [How do I handle page refreshing with an AngularJS Single Page Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21407534/776476)

Answer (score 1):

Use a service to keep a singleton state, which exposes functions to get/reload/etc. Here is a very simple example, just to get you started:

```
.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function($http){
    var state = {};

    var loadFeed = function(){
        $http.get('http://api.example.com').then(function(result){
            state.feed = result.items;                
        });
    };

    // load the feed on initialisation
    loadFeed();

    return {
        getState: function(){
            return state;
        }
    };
}])

.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', 'FeedService', function($scope, FeedService) {        
    // assign the feed container to any scope that you want to use for view
    $scope.cont = FeedService.getState();
})
```

Again, this is very basic, and is simply showing you how you can use a service to store a persistent state between routes.

Comment: This make sense to me - but how those feed get initialized at start up? Even if I add angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services']) to the app.js file, loadFeed() never get's called.

Comment: The other piece that I struggle with here, is that loadFeed() get's called, but getState is returned before the AJAX call is completed.

Comment: Are you using promises?

Comment: @mortsahl I've updated my my code above with the services piece as you suggested, any guides or advice on adding promises to that example?

Comment: $http returns promises for starters. `loadFeed()` gets called as soon as the service is injected somewhere. A container is used to make sure there are no scope binding issues.

Answer (score 0):

if your parameter 'id' in the route contains any character that is being decoded during the http request (like ' ' => '%20') then your route will not work.
try to perform encodeURIComponent() on your string before using it for the routing.